# How to add conditional buildModelConverter for ckeditor5?

Tags: ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am creating a new plugin, in which I add a font tag with style tag for color attribute.

But is it possible to make any change `buildModelConverter` so that if I have selected any other html tag then just add the style tag for that tag and if i have selected some text then wrap them in a font tag ?

My current code is like

```js
buildModelConverter().for( data.modelToView, editing.modelToView )
            .fromAttribute( 'textColor' )
            .toElement( color => {
                const colorElement = new UcColorElement( 'font', {
                    style: `color: ${ color }`
                });
                return colorElement;
            });

        buildViewConverter()
            .for( data.viewToModel )
            .fromElement('font')
            .fromAttribute( 'style', /color/ )
            .toAttribute( viewElement => {
                const color = viewElement.getStyle( 'color' );

                // Do not convert empty, default or unknown alignment values.
                if ( !color ) {
                    return;
                }

                return { key: 'textColor', value: color };
            } );
```

Answer (score 0):

### Short answer

You are asking whether it is possible to change "conversion type" in the converter callback. The answer is no. The moment you decided to use specific converter helper, you decided whether the model attribute is converted to a view attribute or a view element.

You could do that if you wrote your own converter from the scratch. But it might not be necessary (which I explain below).

Writing your own converter wouldn't be THAT difficult in this case (you can base on existing code), but I think that if something is possible to do with provided converters, it is worth doing using them.

### Having an overall idea

When planning a feature, you should think about three matters:

1. How the feature will be represented in the model.
2. What DOM data should be accepted and what view structure will be created by the feature.
3. How a user will interact with the feature (in other words: from UI perspective, how the user will set the feature in the model).

### Theoretical approach to the presented issue

Although we implemented multiple features already (inc. Highlight feature, which is similar), we never felt the need to solve an issue like yours. This makes sense when you consider point 3. from the list above. Applying a feature to a block element usually involves a quite different user experience than applying it to selected text. It almost feels like two separate sub-features.

Having this in mind and knowing how (non-custom) converters are generated and added to the editor, I'd advise following solutions:

#### Split into two features

Treat your feature like it is made of two smaller parts (features, actually) which may (but not necessarily have to) share some code. Each part should:

- define its own schema (allow attribute `textColor` on `$text` vs. allow attribute),
- define its own UI,
- define its own downcast* (model-to-view) and upcast* (view-to-model) converters.

** - This is new terminology we introduced and beta and will be using from now on. We took it from CKEditor 4 and it has the same meaning here.*

I could see that the command could be a common part for both sub-features, but it does not have to be.

*Bonus: To be honest, those two attributes might just have different names to make this problem trivial.*

#### Abandon the idea of adding the attribute to blocks

Although it does not answer your question in a way you might expect, it probably is a correct direction. Especially if the effect of the feature looks same for the "block use" and the "inline use".

Usually, a feature applies to a block when it does not make sense for a range of text inside a block. It looks like what you are trying to achieve is suited for an inline feature. In contrary, for example, it makes no sense to try to apply text alignment only for a part of a paragraph.

I don't know what exactly are your expectation and use case, but with limited knowledge, I'd just advice to have this feature apply attribute only on text. Of course, even then, upcast conversion (view-to-model) could (and should) support reading the attribute from block view elements (`<p>`, etc.) for initial data reading or copy-paste.

### Split into two features - providing converters (1.0.0-beta.1)

*Below I present how to solve this issue providing two converters and assuming that the attribute name is same. To be honest, this seems more like an academic problem, because you could either drop support for blocks or use different attribute names. But let's solve it for the purpose of solving.*

In `1.0.0-beta.1` providing the basic converters is quite easy. [`editor.conversion`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_core_editor_editor-Editor.html#member-conversion) is an instance of [`Conversion`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html) which provides API to add converters to the editor. You will need to provide a total of four converters, two for downcast and two for upcast.

Add converters through [`editor.conversion.for().add()`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_conversion-Conversion.html#function-for) API. Use [`downcast-converters`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcast-converters.html) and [`upcast-converters`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcast-converters.html).

For downcasting, first, specify converter for "`$text` case". Use [`downcastAttributeToElement`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcast-converters.html#static-function-downcastAttributeToElement) as we are downcasting `textColor` attribute to `font` view element.

*`As I was writing code for this case I discovered a bug which makes it impossible to write. I'll create an issue, fix it in a priority order and will edit this answer after it is ready.`*

Keep in mind, that all model and view elements are created via, respectively, [model writer](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html) and [view writer](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_view_writer-Writer.html).

Then specify converter for "elements case". Here we are converting from model attribute to an attribute in a view. Use [`downcastAttributeToAttribute`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_downcast-converters.html#static-function-downcastAttributeToAttribute):

*`As I was writing code for this case I discovered a bug which makes it impossible to write. I'll create an issue, fix it in a priority order and will edit this answer after it is ready.`*

This converter won't be fired if the first converter was already fired because `textColor` attribute will be already consumed by the first converter.

Specifying converters for upcasting is easier because at that point you know if you are converting from view attribute or view element (there's no ambiguity). See [`upcastAttributeToAttribute`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcast-converters.html#static-function-upcastAttributeToAttribute) and [`upcastElementToAttribute`](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_conversion_upcast-converters.html#static-function-upcastElementToAttribute) and use them with `editor.conversion.for( 'upcast' ).add()`.

### 1.0.0-alpha.2 disclaimer

As much as we understand that developers already started writing their features using alpha version, we cannot support it more than giving overall ideas, that you may try to fit in the old code-base.

The API was changed for a reason and it is too time-consuming to provide answers for two APIs. Then, it brings no value to other community members who will be checking these questions in upcoming months.

Finally, providing code for the new API helps us in finding bugs and flaws in the new API, which is much more valuable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Let me explain the situation. I created a color picker plugin, which changes the color of text in editor. It works by adding a font tag and a style attribute with color property.  It works well with other elements then `li` tag. Because if we add font tag inside `li` tag, it will not color the bullets/numbers. Same issue with highlights feature as well. So I was thinking to allow style tag with color on each html tag and add font tag if user selects some text and apply color.